# Linux kernel crc32.h missing from /usr/include/linux

Tags: linux, kernel, kubuntu

I am trying to use the the Linux Kernel crc32 generation facility. I need to do a crc32 of some data to be sent over the wire (independent of any transport methodologies) to an embedded system. The embedded system has a CRC32 engine that calculates the CRC32 of data in a manner that is the same or very similar to that of the kernel. However, all crc related headers related to the kernel are not present in /usr/include/linux and any attempts to manually place them there results in compile time errors. Either missing dependent headers or missing macros.

Doing some searching around isn't yielding any useful results.

Comment: Also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302914/crc32-c-or-c-implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel’s CRC functions are available to the kernel (including modules), but nowhere else. Since you’re referring to `/usr/include/linux` I’m assuming you want to use them from a program outside the kernel.

There are two solutions available to you:

- if your program’s license is compatible with the kernel’s license, you could copy [`lib/crc32.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/crc32.c) to your project and adjust it to suit;
- you can use another implementation of CRC32 (assuming it’s compatible with the target) — [zlib](http://zlib.net/) has one, with a different license.

Comment: Perfect thank you. This program is only needed internally and will not be distributed..period. I have looked into the Zlib crc calculation but the way it is implemented gives different results for the same data input. You can have 3 crc32 calculators with the same polynomial and get 3 different results.

Comment: Yes, I know, that’s why I added the caveat ;-).

Comment: Tho and interesting exercise for the "students" would be implement a module that creates a character/block device that takes input and returns the CRC32 of that input.

Comment: It's actually possible to invoke the kernel's CRC32 code from userland through the crypto API. But I can't think of a good reason to do it: it would be more work to figure out how to do it than to obtain a working CRC32 implementation, and the remote call would be a performance hit. (Accessing kernel crypto from userspace can be useful to use a key that resides in the kernel, but CRC doesn't involve a key. And it can be useful to leverage a hardware accelerator that the kernel has a driver for, but that's not going to help for CRC.)